# Export presets to share

Tags: export

I feel silly asking this.  But is there a way I can export my presets?  For example, I have specific settings for exporting Alembics.  I saved my settings as a preset and now I'd like to share with my teammate?

Answer (score 4):

Presets are saved per Blender version in a folder on disk.

On Windows :

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version number>\scripts\presets
```

On MAC :

```
Library\Application Support\Blender\<version number>\scripts\presets
```

On Linux :

```
~/.config/blender/<version number>/scripts/presets/
```

In there you'll find folders which should be named after specific addons, and maybe subfolders for specific operators. The folders contain .py files. These files are python files, but you can open them with a notepad to see and edit them. They are executed at runtime by Blender to fill in the operator settings. You can share these files, along with the folder structure.

**Be careful when sharing python files**, they can be used to run arbitrary (and potentially malicious) code on your machine. The files may also contain information about your computer, and your folder structure. It depends on the addon. You can check the contents with a plain text editor.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info.  The python sharing bit is something for me to keep in mind as well.  Thank you!